# How to deduct current time by 2 seconds

Tags: android, datetime, time

How to deduct the current time by 2 seconds?

I'd try this code but it does'nt work for me.

```
Date interestingDate = new Date();
(new Date()).getTime() - interestingDate.getTime();
```

I don't know to how to code this.

```
datenow=now.getTime().toLocaleString();
newdate = datenow - 2
```

I would like to get the result like this:

```
9 Mar 2014 2_15_17 - 2 = 9 Mar 2014 2_15_15
```

that is the result by deducting 2 seconds... How?

this is my code:

Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance(); 
datenow=now.getTime().toLocaleString();

i'd try

```
datenow = new Date(now.getTime() - TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2));
```

but i've got an error on "`new Date(now.getTime() - TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2));`"

still got an error

Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance(); 
System.out.println(now.getTime() + " " + now.get(Calendar.SECOND));

now.add(Calendar.SECOND, -2);
System.out.println(now.getTime() + " " + now.get(Calendar.SECOND));

datenow=now.add(Calendar.SECOND, -2);

I have another solution from the suggested answer below.

How about getting the last two digits?

example:

9 Mar 2014 16_23_45.jpeg <-- now get the 45.jpeg

45.jpeg <--- remove the .jpeg so that the 45 will be retain and convert it to value

now 45 - 2 = 43

now get the 9 Mar 2014 16_23_45.jpeg but remove the 45.jpeg and replace it to 43.jpeg.

Maybe that is the best way but i dont know how to cade that in java.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant subtract:

```
Date now = new Date();
Date nowLess2Sec = new Date(now.getTime() - TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2));
```

Comment: Date now = new Date();
Date datenow = new Date(now.getTime()) - TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2)); i've got an error on new Date(now.getTime()) - TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2));

Comment: @androidlearner you have an extra `)` in your code, remove it.

Comment: Date datenow = new Date(now.getTime() - TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2)); but still got an error

Comment: This works but the result is Sun 9 Mar 2014 16_15_31 GMT +8. i want only 9 Mar 2014 16_15_31

Comment: how about by doing this sir. Get the last two digits and then convert to value and subtract it by two. i think that is an easy way but i don't know how to get the last two digits and converting it to value.

Comment: You should have some reading on date formatting, the result is a date, not a string

Answer (score 1):

You can try this also..

```
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(c1.getTime() + " " + c1.get(Calendar.SECOND));

c1.add(Calendar.SECOND, -2);
System.out.println(c1.getTime() + " " + c1.get(Calendar.SECOND));
```

Comment: no....it works for me....have you checked by putting System.out.println(c1.getTime() + " " + c1.get(Calendar.SECOND));

Comment: still got an error:Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance(); System.out.println(now.getTime() + " " + now.get(Calendar.SECOND));
       
       now.add(Calendar.SECOND, -2);
       System.out.println(now.getTime() + " " + now.get(Calendar.SECOND));
       
       datenow=now.add(Calendar.SECOND, -2);

Comment: you are directly assigning it to datenow var.. try like this - Date datenow=new Date(now.getTimeInMillis());
  System.out.println(datenow.toString());

Answer (score 0):

This work is easier with the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library.

```
java.util.Date date = DateTime.now().minusSeconds(2).toDate();
```